# PostgreSQL - select all comments with an ID in its string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some problematic inserted columns in a big table, like this:

```
id | comment 
1 | problematic comment @[some_string](some_string) without ID in it
2 | normal comment @[theunreal](1239329322) good comment with user mention
```

As you can see, there is one comment with ID, and other one with string. I want to select all comments with the strings in the brackets (the problematic once - the first one in the example)

Any idea how I can query such data with Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try a regex like here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE comment !~* '@\[.*?\]\([0-9]+\)';
```

### Demo

The logic above tries to find comments having the proper `(1239329322)` format, i.e. all numbers inside parentheses.  It then matches any record which does *not* have all numbers there.

Comment: @TheUnreal Rather than showing us `(any string)`, you should tell us exactly what we need to find inside the `(...)` in order to flag it.  For example, can bad records have _any_ numbers?  Or would it be all other word characters?  Can you give some examples?